# Cytoscape.js Interactively Change Control Points Bezier Curves

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is it possible in cytoscape.js to allow users to interactively change an `unbundled-bezier` via dragging control points with the mouse? Such as, for example, is possible for curves in http://draw.io? For my application, it would suffice if distance and weight for one control point could be manipulated by dragging it.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it myself. It's right at the top of the list of extensions. Somehow I managed to miss when using google yesterday:

https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-edge-editing